# correlation effect of additional variable on the interaction term in multiple linear regression model

Tags: multiple-regression, difference-in-difference

When we have the following two models:

$$A: y=\tilde\beta_0+\tilde\beta_1x_1+u$$
$$B: y=\hat\beta_0+\hat \beta_1x_1+\hat\beta_2x_2+v$$

We know $$\tilde \beta_1=\hat\beta_1+\hat\beta_2\tilde \delta_1$$ where $\delta_1$ is the slope coefficient of regressing $x_2$ on $x_1$.

Similarly, I was wondering if there is a way to figure out or understand the specific relationship (correlation) between additional variable ($x_2$) and interaction term ($x_1\cdot T$) in the following difference-in-differences specification:

$$A: y=\tilde\beta_0+\tilde\beta_1x_1+\tilde\beta_2T+\tilde\beta_3 x_1 \cdot T+u$$
$$B: y=\hat\beta_0+\hat \beta_1x_1+\hat\beta_2T+\hat\beta_3x_1 \cdot T+\hat\beta_4x_2+v$$